# I should ask to understand the values under the 'attrs' of an object in the following JSON data structure, Ceph, Radosgw, S3, Rados

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph, radosgw

I'd like to discuss the questions I should ask to understand the values under the 'attrs' of an object in the following JSON data structure and evaluate the health of these objects:

I have a sample json output, can you comment on the object state here?

{
"name": "$image.name",
"size": 0,
"tag": "",
"attrs": {
"user.rgw.manifest": "",
"user.rgw.olh.idtag": "$tag.uuid",
"user.rgw.olh.info": "\u0001\u0001�",
"user.rgw.olh.ver": "4"
}
}

What is the purpose of this fields?

`.   "user.rgw.manifest" "user.rgw.olh.idtag" "user.rgw.olh.info" "user.rgw.olh.ver".`

What does the empty value , signify in the context of the object?
How does the absence of value in this field affect the object's health?
How is the content of this field generated? (For example, what does the "$tag" value represent?)
What is the function of this field?
What information does the content of this field carry about the object's status?
What does the content of this field signify? (For instance, what does "4" represent?)
Does this field represent the object's version?
What are the distinguishing features that set this object apart from previous versions?

I did research in the Ceph mail group, talked to experienced people, and am looking for answers to my questions.